# How can a time traveller save Jews on refugee ships like MS St. Louis who were refused entry?

Tags: time-travel

Pretend you travelled back  time and are on  [*MS St. Louis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_St._Louis#The_%22Voyage_of_the_Damned%22), after  sailing to Cuba, North America, and UK. *MS St Louis* still got 620 Jewish passengers, and Captain Schröder is intending to disembark them at Antwerp.

You got no 2020 technologies, no laptop, no smart-phone. You have \$200K  in 2020 US dollars in your US bank accounts.  On *MS St. Louis*, you possess just what an average sea traveller possessed in 1940 (e.g. toiletries, clothing), and your American passport.   Assume your money fails to persuade any official to admit more Jews. I don't know how much fuel *MS St Louis* could buy, and how sea-worthy and far she could sail.

You know in real life, "Of the 620 St. Louis passengers who returned to continental Europe, we determined that eighty-seven were able to emigrate before Germany invaded western Europe on May 10, 1940. 254 passengers in Belgium, France, and the Netherlands after that date died during the Holocaust." Unlike Captain Schröder and the passengers, you know  Nazi Germany will invade Belgium, France, Netherlands.

1. What can you do now to stop Captain Schröder from disembarking these Jews at Antwerp? How save these Jews?
2. "At one point he made plans to wreck the ship on the British coast to force the government to take in the passengers as refugees." Is there some  ignored area that Captain Schröder and his passengers can hide out on and subsist for rest of WW2? I'm thinking of [uninhabited](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Uninhabited_islands) islands like in Carribean, or in the Pacific e.g. [Acteon Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acteon_Group),  [Duke of Gloucester Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke_of_Gloucester_Islands)?

I don't know why in real life, Schröder risked continental Europe, rather than force his way or land on some remote island like Maldives Desert Islands, Chacachacareor, Navassa Island, or Faroe Islands. The rejectors might not even know that  Jews landed. Even once they did, they might not have expelled them at gunpoint. Would Canada care enough about Jewish refugees living on Anticosti Island or Labrador  to  shoot them if they didn't leave? Would Ireland care if they lived on Aran Islands? I don't think Canada or Ireland even patrolled these islands!

Comment: Actions about a character is a story is not worldbuilding.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica how can i edit this to make on topic pls?

Comment: The time-traveller can do whatever the plot demands he do. Time travel is magic.

Comment: @Rhandal, some questions can't be saved. Worldbuilding is about developing and consistently using the rules and systems of a world wherein an infinite number of stories can be told. Storybuilding is about circumstances, character actions and choices, and plot. "How does time travel work?" is a worldbuilding question. "What should my time traveler do?" is a storybuilding question. The only way to make the storybuilding question a worldbuilding question is to remove the characters, dependence on circumstance, and plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Just buy guns***

For that money you could buy plenty of weapons. Just prove to the captain you have the funds, have him contact whatever gun dealers are available and ship out the guns.

Guns cost [a few bucks](https://www.warhistoryonline.com/war-articles/a-rough-guide-of-the-costs-of-guns-during-wwii.html/amp), so just distribute  20k guns to local resistance forces. Then, you can [fight an insurgency](https://www.historynet.com/french-resistance-resistant.htm#:%7E:text=Resistance%20records%20claim%20that%20ultimately,while%20Porch%27s%20research%20shows%2075%2C000.) since you now own 1/4 of the French Resistance.